# Latenise token on query time

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to latenise the query tokens that I use when querying (or filtering). I can do this on application level, but I was wondering if elasticsearch provides an out of the box solution.

I'm using ES 1.7.5 (as a service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default elasticsearch will use the same analyzer at index time and query time but it is possible to specify a [`search_analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-analyzer.html) which will only be used at query time.

Let's take a look at the following example:

```
# First we define an analyzer which will fold non ascii characters called `latinize`.
PUT books
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "latinize": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "book": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string", 
          "analyzer": "standard",       # We use the standard analyzer at index time.
          "search_analyzer": "latinize" # But we use the latinize analyzer at query time.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# Now let's create a document and search for it with a non latinized string.
POST books/book
{
  "name": "aaoaao"
}

POST books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "ääöääö"
    }
  }
}
```

And bam! There is our document.

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "books",
        "_type": "book",
        "_id": "AVkIXdNyDpmDHTvI6Cp1",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "name": "aaoaao"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Yes I'm aware of the different phases in analysing, but the thing is, asciifolding will remove accents, will it though latenise, for instance a greek character?

Comment: That should be possible with the [ICU plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/character-folding.html).